# Infinite loop when using ComponentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

I want to get a bunch of answers based on the question_ID whenever I click next and previous button, but when I put it in the componentDidUpdate, it does exactly what I want, but its loop infinitely, is there any way I can fix it?

The first Axios.get is fine, it gets a bunch of question based on quiz_ID, then the second Axios.get is each question have a bunch of answers based on question_ID

Here is my code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {Component} from 'react'

class QuizForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
                    step: 0,
                    dataQuestion: [],
                    question: 1,
                    answer: []
        }
    }
// ------------------
        async componentDidMount(){
            await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/quiz/'+this.props.quizID)
            .then(res=>{
                this.setState({
                    dataQuestion: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
            
            await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/answer/'+this.state.dataQuestion[this.state.step]?.question_ID)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log('Hello')
                this.setState({
                    answer: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }

        async componentDidUpdate(){
            const id = this.state.dataQuestion[this.state.step]?.question_ID;
            axios.get('http://localhost:3000/answer/'+id)
            .then(res=>{
                this.setState({
                    answer: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }

// -------------------
    handleNext = ()=>{
        if (this.state.step === this.state.dataQuestion.length - 1){
            return
        }
        this.setState({step: this.state.step + 1})
        this.setState({question: this.state.question+1})
    }
    handlePrevious = ()=>{
        if(this.state.step === 0){
            return
        }
        this.setState({step: this.state.step - 1})
        this.setState({question: this.state.question-1})
    }
// ---------------------
    render(){
            const {dataQuestion, question, answer} = this.state
                console.log(answer)
        return(
            <>
            <div className="column middle">
            <div className="game-details-container">
                <h1> Question : <span id="question-number"></span> {question}/{dataQuestion.length}</h1>
            </div>
                    <div className="game-quiz-container">    
                                        {dataQuestion[this.state.step]?.question_desc}
                        <div className="game-options-container">
                            <span>
                                <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="option" className="radio" value="optionA" />
                                <label htmlFor="option-one" className="option" id="option-one-label">A</label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="next-button-container">
                            <button onClick = {()=>this.handlePrevious()}>Previous Question</button>
                            <button onClick = {()=>this.handleNext()}>Next Question</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                </>
        );
    }
}

export default QuizForm
```

Comment: You need to compare previous prop and and current prop in component did update. Only call axios if that comparison are not equal

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` watches updates in your state and executes when it detects any. The problem here is that you're using it to update your own state in an asynchronous way. It means that at first, your component detects an update, then plans to change its state for later. When that planned change in your state happens, your `componentDidUpdate` gets triggered again, and this repeats over and over.

Comment: Can you guys give me more instructions, I still don't know how to compare the props, because I think I'm doing with the state, not the props, I don't know if I think it correctly or not.